# MySQL column not found despite being declared?

Tags: mysql, select

This query works:

```
select d.*,
(6371 * 3.1415926 * SQRT((:lat - dl.lat) * (:lat - dl.lat) + COS(:lat / 57.2957795) * COS(dl.lat / 57.2957795) * (:long - dl.long) * (:long - dl.long)) / 180) as xdistance
from `dudes` as d
left join `dude_locations` as dl on (dl.id_dude = d.id)
where 
(6371 * 3.1415926 * SQRT((:lat - dl.lat) * (:lat - dl.lat) + COS(:lat / 57.2957795) * COS(dl.lat / 57.2957795) * (:long - dl.long) * (:long - dl.long)) / 180) <= dl.distance
group by d.id
limit 20
```

However, this query throws a "column `xdistance` not found" error:

```
select d.*,
(6371 * 3.1415926 * SQRT((:lat - dl.lat) * (:lat - dl.lat) + COS(:lat / 57.2957795) * COS(dl.lat / 57.2957795) * (:long - dl.long) * (:long - dl.long)) / 180) as xdistance
from `dudes` as d
left join `dude_locations` as dl on (dl.id_dude = d.id)
where 
xdistance <= dl.distance
group by d.id
limit 20
```

All I'm trying to do is make it so the same calculation isn't made twice. Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your query needs some improvement.  You are using `left join`, and then a condition on the second table turns it into an `inner join`.  You have the distance calculation in the `select`, but a `group by` that doesn't include those variables -- so you will get an indeterminate result.

Comment: The working query gives me the exact results I want. How would you write it? Could you possibly create an answer with how you would write the query? I am not trying to get you to do my work for me, I am just curious.

Comment: . . It might give you the results you want *now*.  But when you use features that are explicitly documented not to work (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html), then you run the risk of the code failing to work at any time.  I think you can fix the query just by putting the `distance` calculation in an operator like `min()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
where 
d.xdistance <= dl.distance
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I now get `Unknown column d.distance`.

Comment: @inkd i think error would be Unknown column d.xdistance

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the query you want is something like this:

```
select d.*,
       MIN((6371 * 3.1415926 * SQRT((:lat - dl.lat) * (:lat - dl.lat) + COS(:lat / 57.2957795) * COS(dl.lat / 57.2957795) * (:long - dl.long) * (:long - dl.long)) / 180) ) as xdistance
from `dudes` as d left join
     `dude_locations` as dl
     on (dl.id_dude = d.id)
group by d.id
having xdistance <= min(dl.distance)
limit 20;
```